# Diifference between 資金 and 資本

Tags: word-choice

Both 資金 and 資本 appear to mean 'funds' or 'capital' but again I do not understand if or what difference exists between them.

Comment: FYI: [「資金」と「資本」の違いとは](https://meaning-dictionary.com/「資金」と「資本」の違いとは？分かりやすく解/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**資本** refers to initial properties/resources you prepare or invest to start a business. Typically, it refers to money, but technically speaking, you can start a business with anything as 資本. For example, in [わらしべ長者](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Straw_Millionaire), one may say the protagonist's 資本 was a piece of straw. People often figuratively say 体が資本だ referring to blue collar workers and athletes whose income is directly based on their healthy body.

**資本金**, as the kanji 金 suggests, refers to money invested to start a company. Laypeople use this word loosely, but it's a complicated concept when used as a strict legal term. The Japanese law requires to you declare the 資本金 when you create and register a company, but it can be as little as one yen. The actual money to run the company can be borrowed from a bank, but such money is not called 資本金. 資本金 is a semi-fixed value (e.g., the 資本金 of Nintendo is 10,065,400,000 yen), and is mostly unrelated to how healthily the company is run each year.

**資金** is money used to actually run a company every day. Running out of 資金 basically means going bankrupt.

Answer (score 2):

Partly based on [a thesaurus entry](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/thsrs/8094/meaning/m1u/%E8%B3%87%E6%9C%AC/).

Both can mean *money with which a person conducts economic activities* and are interchangeable to some extent.

資本 is usually money you do or start business with and used more in business or economics contexts. Some examples:

- capitalism : 資本主義 (not 資金主義)
- make an investment : 資本を投下する. It should be less idiomatic to say 資金を投下する.

Another expression worth mentioning would be 体が資本=*The body is the capital*, which means *being physically fit is important in doing something (or anything)*. In this sense, it is close to 元手 which also means *money you start/do business with*. The difference is the implied size of business is smaller for 元手. Related to the other question you posted, it should roughly hold that 事業：資本 = 商売：元手.

資金 is more like a way of expressing *money*. As such it can be used in everyday conversations.

- I don't have money to buy a house. :  家を買う資金がない
- raise funds : 資金を調達する
- money laundering : 資金洗浄

The second one might look contradictory to the above comment, but I guess it is because what startups get is actual money (more or less).

---

If you look at any decent company webpage, it has a profile page where 資本金 is mentioned.  I don't know the details, but it is the money with which the owner started the company.